# SFML render texture: cant draw to negative coordinates

Tags: c++, c++14, sfml

I'm trying to draw an isometric map of tiles to a `RenderTexture`. Problem is anything I draw to negative coordinates in the `RenderTexture` is not displayed, which means the entire map gets cut in half.

[image: Screenshot]

A simple example showing the problem.

```
sf::RenderTexture renderTexture;
renderTexture.create(64 * width, 32 * height);

sf::RectangleShape rectangleShape(sf::Vector2f(100, 100));
rectangleShape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
rectangleShape.setPosition(-50, -50);
renderTexture.draw(rectangleShape);

renderTexture.display();

sf::Sprite sprite1;
sprite1.setPosition(0, 0);
sprite1.setTexture(renderTexture.getTexture());

window.draw(sprite1);
```

Only 1/4th of the rectangle shape will be shown. Any way to fix this without offsetting my entire map (and in turn all entities), so its only in positive coordinates?

Comment: You cannot draw outside of the bounds of a `RenderTexture`.  Think of it like a paint canvas; you can't paint on the air outside of the canvas.  Your world and entity coordinates don't have to change; try using `sf::View` to make a "camera".

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for suggesting using a View, 0x5453!

If anyone else comes across this, heres my solution;

```
sf::RenderTexture renderTexture;
renderTexture.create(tilesize * mapWidth, tilesize * mapHeight);
sf::View view = renderTexture.getView();
view.setCenter(0, 0);
renderTexture.setView(view);

// Draw stuff to the renderTexture

renderTexture.display();
sf::Sprite sprite;
sprite.setTexture(renderTexture.getTexture());
sprite.setPostion(-(width*tilesize)/2), -(width*tilesize)/2)
window.draw(sprite);
```

Very simplified, but thats the gist of it.

Basically setting the center of the render texture to screen coordinates (0, 0). And then offsetting it back before rendering.